# The text is uniformly distributed on each page

Tags: distributions, fill

I have the problem since yesterday that the text on each page in not distributed from up to down but uniformly on the page, here is an example of a page and the code https://gyazo.com/6f2bb0b879f3fd120c21ce808634e367

```
Sea $F$ este número. \par 
Como $F$ mide a $A$ , $B$ y $C$,\\
en particular mide a $A$ y $B$; \\
por lo que medirá al máximo común divisor de $A$ y $B$, que es $D$, \hfill 
[VII-2, Cor.] \par 
Pero también mide a $C$; \par 
por lo que medirá al máximo común divisor de $D$ y $C$, que es $E$, \hfill [VII-2, Cor.] \\
pero $F$ era mayor que $E$, lo cual es imposible. \par 
Por lo tanto ningún número mayor que $E$  medirá a $A$ , $B$ y $C$; \\
por lo que $E$ es el máximo común divisor de $A$ , $B$ y $C$.

\subsubsection*{Demostración análoga:}
Sean $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}\setminus\{ 1 \} $ coprimos. \\
$MCD(a,b)= d $ \hfill [VII-2] \\
$MCD(d,c)=e $ \hfill [VII-2] \\  
Entonces, \\ $e=MCD(a,b,c)$ \\ ya que: \\
$MCD(d,c)=e \implies e\mid c \ $ y $\ e\mid d$\\
$d\mid a \ $ y $\ d\mid b \implies e\mid a \ $ y $\ e\mid b$ \\
Por lo tanto $e\mid a \ $,$\ e\mid b \ $ y $\ e\mid c$ \\
Si $e \not= MCD(a,b,c) \implies \exists g>e \ $ tal que $\ g=MCD(a,b,c) \ \ $, entonces,\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (main) [align=right] {$g\mid a \ $ y $\ g\mid b \implies g\mid d$ \\ $g\mid c$ }; \hfill hola
\begin{scope} [node distance=0.4em]
    \node [right=of main] {$\implies g\mid MCD(d,c) \implies g\mid e $\hspace{3.32cm} [VII-2,Cor.] }; 
\end{scope}
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] [thick] (2.3,-0.6) -- (2.3,0.6);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\textbf{¡Contradicción!} $\implies e=MCD(a,b,c)$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a short compilable code reproducing the problem.

Comment: Why does your code contain so many explicit line breaks? Doing so pretty much flies in the face of what TeX and LaTeX are designed to achieve.

Comment: Line breaks are "\\"? If it's so is because I'm doing a translation of a text and I want to maintain the "one statement, one line". Is it bad for LaTeX?

Comment: The standard LaTeX (and PlainTeX) way to create a line-break is to provide a completely blank line...